# Strange characters in string gotten from API can't decode

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I'm creating a program that grabs data from an API and stores it in my own database. The problem is some of the stings have some sort of character code where quotation marks should be. Upon further inspection, it appears to be hex code for the quotation mark, but it's fantastically double escaped, confusing me along with all my decoders. I believe the string comes in as ascii and I don't have any other issues with the other characters.

I know I can simply replace the specific character code with the actual character, but I need to catch stuff like this in the future. If it is hex, I need to comb strings for hex codes and replace them procedurally.

I've tried

```
clean_val = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', val).encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

I've gotten myself quite confused about the whole thing

```
response = session.get(url)
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(response.content)

b'{"Description":"American Assets Trust, Inc. (the \\\u0093company\\\u0094) is a full service, vertically ..."}'
```

I think the string is stored on their database like  \" to satisfy some SQL escaping protocol. When I get it, the escaping slash gets mixed in with the character code, thereby messing up the encoding.

Comment: Some variation of Ascii2Uni might help. Perhaps there is a Python binding or port.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these characters are from text encoded as cp1252.  It's possible to decode them

```
>>> bs = b'{"Description":"American Assets Trust, Inc. (the \\u0093company\\u0094) is a full service, vertically ..."}'
>>> d = json.loads(bs)
>>> s = d['Description']
>>> decoded = s.encode('latin-1').decode('cp1252')
>>> decoded
'American Assets Trust, Inc. (the “company”) is a full service, vertically ...'
```

but you will have to replace them manually, using `str.replace` or `str.translate`

```
>>> table = str.maketrans('“”', '""')
>>> decoded = s.encode('latin-1').decode('cp1252')
>>> decoded.translate(table)
'American Assets Trust, Inc. (the "company") is a full service, vertically ...'
```